BIRT Expression to Filter Data Based on Consecutive Instances
I'm working on a BIRT report and need help refining a data filtering expression.
Problem:
I have an existing BIRT template (.rptdesign) and sample XML data.
I've removed the first two columns from the report.
The goal is to display only rows where a specific value occurs 7 or more consecutive times.




Attempts:
I've created a BIRT expression but it's not producing the desired results.
Computed Column Name is maxConsecutiveDays, data type is Integer
var consecutiveDays = 0;
var maxConsecutiveDays = 0;
var lastDate = null;

for (var i = 0; i < dataSetRow["CalendarDate"].length; i++) {
    var currentDate = new Date(dataSetRow["CalendarDate"][i]);
    
    if (lastDate) {
        var diffDays = (currentDate - lastDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
        
        if (diffDays === 1) {
            consecutiveDays++;
        } else {
            if (consecutiveDays > maxConsecutiveDays) {
                maxConsecutiveDays = consecutiveDays;
            }
            consecutiveDays = 1;
        }
    } else {
        consecutiveDays = 1;
    }
    
    lastDate = currentDate;
}

if (consecutiveDays > maxConsecutiveDays) {
    maxConsecutiveDays = consecutiveDays;
}

maxConsecutiveDays;


Is the question about java or JavaScript? Remove the incorrect tag.

I am working with java based eclipse, but BIRT requires me to add expressions using JavaScript

Questions should be tagged with a language if they are about a specific programming issue related to that language. If a product is implemented in a language doesn't automatically qualify for that tag.

Alright, I have added the programming languages.
